# What are the limitations of Serialization?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, save

As I have stated in the title I have some doubts about serialization I'd like to brush off.

- Does serialization save EVERY single variable type? E.G BufferedImage
- Will arrays in my object be serialized?
- If so, Keeping in mind that I have much object experience in Pascal, will an array list(dynamic array) be serialized well?
- If I will have trouble doing this, may someone please provide me a good solution on how to store an object containing arrays, any variables and array lists; for future use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To be serializable, a Java object has to implement the `Serializable` interface. So no, not every Java type will be serializable, you will need to check if any of the super classes implement `Serializable`.
- Arrays (the primitive type) are by default serializable
- An `ArrayList`, as a `List` implementation, is also serializable
- We don't know what exactly you are trying to do, if you provide some more details and/or code samples we could try to help

Comment: Well I'm not doing anything specific, just need to mash out a good way to save my games. Since I want be a game developer and all, pascal was lame and wouldn't let me save dynamic arrays.So when I asked if would have any trouble I just meant if it really couldn't serialize arrays and stuff what I could do.